# Run shell script globally in Git bash in Windows

Tags: windows, bash, git, shell

I have a shell script that I want to run globally. It's current directory is

```
~/directory/script.sh
```

I can run the script only from the directory in which the script is located, however, I'd like to run it from every directory, not just the one that it's in.

I'm using Git bash in Windows 10. I've tried putting this line at the top of the file:

```
#!usr/local/bin
```

but that didn't work (probably because I'm using Windows), the bash said it doesn't recognize it.

I also tried using `alias` but it's not really a solution.

Is there a different way to run a shell script globally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find your root directory of Git Bash installation and go to `/usr/bin`.

For my case, full path is : 
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

Copy your script there (you will need Administrator rights). I named my script as `my-script.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Open Git Bash as an Administrator and give your script executable right :

```sh
chmod +x /usr/bin/my-script.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

*git bash* loads its global scripts from a directory `/usr/bin` which it creates in its windows installation folder, if you place your script there, you should be able to call it from any directory you're in while using *git bash*

Comment: did you try calling it complete with extension(like .sh), because i just tested it before posting this and works in git bash, as it stores all the major commands it uses like ssh in that directory only, also, please check you are in the correct installation directory that you're using git-bash from and has to be placed in its child `/usr/bin` not `/bin`

Comment: Thanks for your patients! I figured it out now. thanks for tour help